# Html5 video not working/playing on Safari

Tags: html, video, safari

I have created a new website for a friend of mine and now the video we have on the welcome screen is not working in Safari, in all other browsers it works fine.

Website: http://www.mangohoian.com

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], rather than a link to the site. Additionally, explain what "not working" means. You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Your video is .webm, which seems [not to be supported by Safari](https://webm.html5.org/).
I transcoded to mp4 and seems to work okay in Safari. You'll need to change your HTML to either offer the alternatives in the `<video>` tag, or make use of the `canPlayType` function to determine which source to present.

Transcoding parameters: `./ffmpeg -y -i Mango3_CLIPCHAMP_keep.webm -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags faststart Mango3_CLIPCHAMP_keep.mp4`

I also uploaded the version [here](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AhulbaZgpLZTjMUOCMbDvIPQAGWqqg) if you want to grab it (file will expire in 30 days)

Comment: Thank you! this solved the problem didn't see that is was a webm :(

Comment: Great, any chance of a tick for correct answer ;) If you've grabbed the mp4 let me know and I'll delete it as well (you might want to optimize it a bit more, as it's a little larger filesize than I'd recommend for a background video)

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser version, its supported from Safari 10 and above.
Hope this helps